# How to get the height of a text field in Processing?

Tags: processing

I am displaying a number of text fields with different fonts and colors, beneath each other.
The problem is, there seems to be no way of calculating how high each field is, making it problematic to line them out neatly.

My code:

```
fill(245);
textFont(alfaslab,48);
text("Title text here, can be very short or very long", 20, 60, 580, 180);
textFont(asapbold,30);
text("More text here, can also be very short or very long", 20, 160, 480, 280);
fill(230);
textFont(asapreg,23);
text("More text here, can also be very short or very long", 20, 460, 480, 280);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this helps you?

```java
PFont f;

void setup() {
  size (550, 200);

  int fontSize = 40;// change here and averything goes along...


  f = createFont("arial", fontSize);
  textFont(f);
  String hi = "Hi, there. How's every thing?";

  //arbitrary
  float xPos = 20;
  float yPos = height/2;

  text(hi, xPos, yPos);

  // width
  float textWid = textWidth(hi);

  //lower y position including descent of text
  float lower = yPos + textDescent();

  //upper calculated from lowewr point
  float upper = lower - fontSize;

  // your own box :)
  stroke(150);
  line(xPos, lower, xPos + textWid, lower);
  line(xPos, upper, xPos + textWid, upper );
  line(xPos, upper, xPos, lower );
  line(xPos + textWid, upper, xPos + textWid, lower );

  // not considering descent
  stroke(255, 220, 220, 180);
  line(xPos, yPos, xPos + textWid, yPos);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this works only for a single line. The problem is that I don't know how long the text will be, and perhaps it wraps.
I solved that by using width and height like this: text("hello",x,y,width,height). That automatically wraps text, but then you don't know how much of that space is actually filled with text.

Comment: @PietBinnenbocht did you arrive to a solution for the multiline height problem?

Comment: I didn't pursuit it :) But you can make your own function to mesure how much space you are going to need... Like: set the font  and size, mesure  using textWidth, split as necessary, count the lines, multiply by font vertical size, and... done :) Or even make  your own text box.

Comment: Yes, I solved it by using the function I posted as answer. It breaks up a text into an array of single lines. You can then print each line manually so you always know how much vertical space is used.

Answer (score 0):

This code breaks a long text into an array of single lines, according to the width you specify.
You can then display each line one by one, so you will always know how much vertical space is used. I found this answer somewhere here on Stackoverflow. Can't find the original post anymore.

```
//
// this list contains strings that fit within maxWidth
//
StringList wordWrap(String s, int maxWidth) {
  // Make an empty ArrayList
  StringList a = new StringList();
  float w = 0;    // Accumulate width of chars
  int i = 0;      // Count through chars
  int rememberSpace = 0; // Remember where the last space was
  // As long as we are not at the end of the String
  while (i < s.length()) {
    // Current char
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    w += textWidth(c); // accumulate width
    if (c == ' ') rememberSpace = i; // Are we a blank space?
    if (w > maxWidth) {  // Have we reached the end of a line?
      String sub = s.substring(0,rememberSpace); // Make a substring
      // Chop off space at beginning
      if (sub.length() > 0 && sub.charAt(0) == ' ') sub = sub.substring(1,sub.length());
      // Add substring to the list
      a.append(sub);
      // Reset everything
      s = s.substring(rememberSpace,s.length());
      i = 0;
      w = 0;
    } 
    else {
      i++;  // Keep going!
    }
  }

  // Take care of the last remaining line
  if (s.length() > 0 && s.charAt(0) == ' ') s = s.substring(1,s.length());
  a.append(s);

  return a;
}
```

Example of usage: define a global variable texty. This keeps track of the current y position for a new text line. Update this every time a new line of text is added.

```
function startDrawing() {
    texty=30;
    textFont(asapreg,23);
    displayWrapped("long text here", 23);

    texty+=30;
    textFont(asapreg,20);
    displayWrapped("another long text here", 20);
  }
```

Now we call the function that breaks the text into an array, and draw each line one by one.

```
  //
  // display each line of text one by one
  //
  void displayWrapped(String str, int fontSize) {
   StringList myTexts = wordWrap(str, 420);
   // loop through lines
    for (int i=0; i < myTexts.size(); i++) {
      String s = myTexts.get(i);
      text(s, 420, texty);
      texty += fontSize;
    }
  }
```